# Python opening files with no window

Tags: python-3.x, windows-7

I'm trying to play a sound file with python. But when i use the os.system (path\audio.mp3) this opens windows media player and plays the file. Is there a way to make it not open the window but still play the sound?

I've also tried using sound libraries to play the sound like pyaudio to no succes.

Comment: What are you running in `os.system`

Comment: An audio file path

Comment: You're just putting in the path?

Comment: Yes with audio.mp3 at the end

Comment: Could you put that in e question? It will make it easier to answer your question

Comment: I've edited the post. is it more clear now?